# how to create a TextFormField function in flutter

Tags: flutter, textformfield

TextFormField function in flutter
A FormField that contains a TextField.
This is a convenience widget that wraps a TextField widget in a FormField.

```
static formField({
    required String label,
    String? initialValue,
    FormFieldSetter? onSaved,
    ValueChanged? onChanged,
    Icon? icon,
    int? maxLines,
    TextEditingController? controller,
    TextInputType? keyboard,
  }) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 8),
      child: TextFormField(
        validator: (value) {
          if (value!.isEmpty) {
            return 'please type the $label above';
          }
        },
        initialValue: initialValue,
        controller: controller,
        maxLines: maxLines,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        onSaved: onSaved,
        keyboardType: keyboard,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          label: Text(label),
          prefixIcon: icon,
          hintText: 'Type $label here',
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: how you like to use `formField`?

Answer (score 0):

```
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 8),
  child: Container(
    child: TextFormField(
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return 'please type the $label above';
        }
      },
      initialValue: initialValue,
      controller: controller,
      maxLines: maxLines,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      onSaved: onSaved,
      keyboardType: keyboard,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        label: Text(label),
        prefixIcon: icon,
        hintText: 'Type $label here',
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

i think this will work... wrap the TextFormField inside the container.. if there is any wrong syntax change it

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer. @Muthu Vijay .

Comment: @DSDmark ok i have explained some more clearly what i have done...
in the query posted, the person returning a Padding widget whose child is TextFormField.
when we do padding to InputFields, it wont work properly (i dont know why but i have experienced).
so previously the child of Padding widget is TextFormField but in my solution, the child of Padding widget is Container widget and the Container widget's child is a TextFormField, which gives us the expected result.
I hope this have cleared your doubt :)